# Pentaho Error while importing data and cleaning

Tags: sql, pentaho, pentaho-cde, pentaho-design-studio

So we receive a file named a every day and pentaho fetches the file and removes the delimiter and loads the data into sql table the process did not have any changes done after its successful run , but now we are getting this weird  error message and we are unable to figure out what is the issue.

```
2015/08/11 13:10:06 - read a file.0 - ERROR (version 4.3.0-stable, build 16786 from 2012-04-24 14.11.32 by buildguy) : Unexpected error
2015/08/11 13:10:06 - Table output.0 - Prepared statement : INSERT INTO dbo.M_FILE (FILE_NAME) VALUES ( ?)
2015/08/11 13:10:06 - read a file.0 - ERROR (version 4.3.0-stable, build 16786 from 2012-04-24 14.11.32 by buildguy) : java.lang.NullPointerException
2015/08/11 13:10:06 - read a file.0 - ERROR (version 4.3.0-stable, build 16786 from 2012-04-24 14.11.32 by buildguy) :  at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.BaseStep.getRowFrom(BaseStep.java:1798)
2015/08/11 13:10:06 - read a file.0 - ERROR (version 4.3.0-stable, build 16786 from 2012-04-24 14.11.32 by buildguy) :  at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.textfileinput.TextFileInput.processRow(TextFileInput.java:882)
2015/08/11 13:10:06 - read a file.0 - ERROR (version 4.3.0-stable, build 16786 from 2012-04-24 14.11.32 by buildguy) :  at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:50)
2015/08/11 13:10:06 - read a file.0 - ERROR (version 4.3.0-stable, build 16786 from 2012-04-24 14.11.32 by buildguy) :  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Hard to say, I would try to isolate the problem: Read the file(s) withoud DB-Connection in a new transformation, does it work?
Then try the other part: Database-connections still works? Try without variables ... It worked before without changes: Maybe the data-input changed?
Otherwise I think it's needed a bitmore information because of this general error message.

Comment: those are the only error messages which we are receiving.